# How would I get the nav bar to scroll down when clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, nav

How would i do that in JavaScript or j Query? I have been trying to do this for ages but couldn't so it would really be appreciated if you could help! :) Also if you have any tips or tricks or anything that i may have done wrong then it would be nice if you could also mention that!

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Redirected</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        <font face="verdana" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class = "title">
            <h1>Redirected.</h1>
        </div>
        <div class = "title-mobile">
            <h1>&#9776; Redirected.</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="title-solgan">
            <p>THE HOME OF GAMING</p>
        </div>


        <div class="nav-bar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href = "index.html">HOME</li></a>
                <li><a href = "news.html">NEWS</li></a>
                <li><a href = "#">REVIEWS</li></a>
                <li><a href = "strategy.html">PLAYSTATION</li></a>
                <li><a href = "strategy.html">XBOX</li></a>
                <li><a href = "strategy.html">PC</li></a>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class = "main-story">
            <h1>14 Things Every Steam User Should Know </h1>
        </div>


        <div class = "trending-games">
            <h1> Games Trending </h1>
            <li>Destiny</li>
            <li>Fallout 4</li>
            <li>Mad Max </li>
            <li>Metal Gear Solid </li>
        </div>

        <div class="latest-game-news">
            <h1>Latest Game News </h1>
            <li>Minecraft Will Support Oculus VR Next      Year</li>
            <li>Fallout 4 Meets Grand Theft Auto 5 in Latest PC Mod</li>
            <li>Halo 6: 343 Says Sequel is in the 'Planning'     Stage</li>
            <li>The Sims Boss Leaves EA</li>
        </div>

        <div class="more-game-news">
            <h1>More Game News</h1>
            <li>Xbox Free Games With Gold October 2015</li>
            <li>EA Working on Netflix for Games</li>
            <li>Assassin's Creed Syndicate's New Story   Trailer</li>
            <li>Uncharted 4 Delayed</li>
        </div>
        <footer>This is a sticky footer</footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So, what did you try already? Isn't your javascript missing?

Comment: yes but i got it wrong

Comment: You can use jQuery's [`scrollTop()`](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)

Comment: That doesn't matter, we could at least tell: a) if you did an effort or your just asking us to code something for you, b) where you made your mistakes and how you could get your piece of code to work

Comment: `I have been trying to do this for ages`..hmmm..seriously?

Comment: ffs all im asking for is that someone helps me

Comment: Stack Overflow is for teaching programmers to fish (I mean that figuratively but we should pause and laugh at the literal interpretation for a moment). We tend to help those who show they are willing to help themselves. We ask for more details (even if they're wrong) so that we can see what you've tried, tell you where it went wrong, and explain the answer so you're better equipped for the future. No one here will write a solution for you from scratch, or at least they shouldn't.